# Variable is null - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I am trying to use the demo kendo ui dropdownlist. For some reason when I create my variable "dropdownlist" to set its datasource, the variable is null Can anyone see what needs to be changed?

Here is the demo of it being used http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index

```
function getcombo() {
        var data = getVillages();
        console.log(data);
        var dropdownlist = $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");
        console.log(dropdownlist);                                //error here
        dropdownlist.setDataSource(data);      
    };
```

In my html I have:

```
<div id="example">
        <div id="cap-view" class="demo-section k-header">
            <h2>Customize your Kendo Cap</h2>
            <div id="cap" class="black-cap"></div>
            <div id="options">
            <h3>Cap Color</h3>
            <input id="color" value="1" />

            <h3>Cap Size</h3>
            <select id="size">
                <option>S - 6 3/4"</option>
                <option>M - 7 1/4"</option>
                <option>L - 7 1/8"</option>
                <option>XL - 7 5/8"</option>
            </select>

            <button class="k-button" id="get">Customize</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <style scoped>
            .demo-section {
                width: 460px;
                height: 300px;
            }
            .demo-section h2 {
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-size: 1em;
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
            #cap {
                float: left;
                width: 242px;
                height: 225px;
                margin: 20px 30px 30px 0;
                background-image: url('../content/web/dropdownlist/cap.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-color: transparent;
            }
            .black-cap {
                background-position: 0 0;
            }
            .grey-cap {
                background-position: 0 -225px;
            }
            .orange-cap {
                background-position: 0 -450px;
            }
            #options {
                padding: 1px 0 30px 30px;
            }
            #options h3 {
                font-size: 1em;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin: 25px 0 8px 0;
            }
            #get {
                margin-top: 25px;
            }
        </style>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var data = [
                        { text: "Black", value: "1" },
                        { text: "Orange", value: "2" },
                        { text: "Grey", value: "3" }
                    ];

                    // create DropDownList from input HTML element
                    $("#color").kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "text",
                        dataValueField: "value",
                        dataSource: data,
                        index: 0,
                        change: onChange
                    });

                    // create DropDownList from select HTML element
                    $("#size").kendoDropDownList();

                    var color = $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");

                    color.select(0);
                    var size = $("#size").data("kendoDropDownList");

                    function onChange() {
                        var value = $("#color").val();
                        $("#cap")
                            .toggleClass("black-cap", value == 1)
                            .toggleClass("orange-cap", value == 2)
                            .toggleClass("grey-cap", value == 3);
                    };

                    $("#get").click(function() {
                        alert('Thank you! Your Choice is:\n\nColor ID: '+color.value()+' and Size: '+size.value());
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
```

Comment: why are you saying `var dropdownlist = $("#color").data("kendoDropDownList");` I think you should be saying just `var dropdownlist = $("#color")`

Comment: Create a jsfiddle or codepen project  and share us the link, so we can see where you call `getCombo` and how fits into your code.

Answer (score 1):

my guess would be "jQuery.data( element, key, value )"

normally 'null' only exists if the user sets the variable to explicitly be 'null' otherwise it would be undefined

by the way, you can console.log(arg1, arg2, etc.) with commas to log them all at once on the same line